# Is there a way to make a node property value the default?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, image, interpolation

I'm making a Minecraft animation and the only way the render comes out with clean pixelated textures and not blurry textures is if I set the image interpolation in the shader node editor to *Closest*.

It seems that I have to do this for every kind of block. Is there a way I can just set closest to the default interpolation within a project (so whenever I have to append a new Minecraft object, it will have the right interpolation)?

If I can't set the interpolation to a default value, can I at least apply the *Closest* interpolation to everything in the scene?

Answer (score 6):

I'll post another answer since this one will actually solve your problem (I hope). Use this script to set the interpolation of each and every one of your "Image Texture" nodes to "Closest" :

```
import bpy

for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    if not mat.node_tree:
        continue
    for node in mat.node_tree.nodes:
        if node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE':
            node.interpolation = 'Closest'
```

[image]

[How to run a script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11604548/7092409)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can't modify the default setting easily but you can use a simple node group to force the behaviour wherever you want to use your image texture node :

[image]

Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/168033/86891

Comment: I realized by re-reading your question that this doesn't answer it...

Comment: It could function as a workaround. Instead of adding a new *Image Texture* node every time instead add a new *Group Node* with an image texture already set as *Closest Interpolation*, then ungroup the node before regular use.

Comment: The problem is that I import the model from mineways, so it automatically creates the textures and nodes. But everything is set to Linear, so I have to go back to every single type of block and change the interpolation to Closest. I don't have to create nodes, just edit them.

Comment: Does [my other answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/181959/86891) help you ?