# Changing node that effects to all material

Tags: node-editor, shaders, color

I'm trying to make something like colour palette in every material, for my animation

I dont have idea, so I just use color ramp to make it, like picture below,
and name it as "COLOR PALETTE"

[image]

I do copy these "COLOR PALETTE" to all material,
so, If need the color in every material I just use eyedropper to get the color

but, sometimes I need to change the arrangement of my "COLOR PALETTE"

1. Is there a simple way to make "COLOR PALETTE" in blender?
2. How to make the "COLOR PALETTE" that I made linked, so if I change those "COLOR PALETTE", it would change too in other material

I can do duplicate object linked (ALT + D), so if I change the object, it would affects to other object,
so, how to use is in a node mode?

Comment: You can use this color ramp in a group, this group can be shared between mutliple materials. see : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172761/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-node-property-value-the-default/172770#172770 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168028/build-abstract-parent-shader/168033#168033

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer, you can open an *Image Editor* viewport window.  Set it to *Paint* mode and create a new image.

[image]

You might want to fake user the image to save it.

Set your brush to full strength.

[image]

Below the brush settings you'll see the color picker.  You can use the eyedropper tool on anything in blender, or copy and paste a color over.  Once you bring your colors over and you can even do some mixing with the smear tool.

[image]

Comment: Cool! I just learned a new trick, this way is very handy for my project because I have to insert keyframe in every change of my color, I really appreciate it, thank man!

Answer (score 6):

Rather than using a Color Ramp, you can create a Node Group to hold your colours as separate RGB input nodes. Your materials can then use the same Node Group to make use of those colours and changing the contents of the Node Group will affect everything that uses it.

To create your Node Group, first create all of your RGB nodes and highlight them all (by dragging a box around them). In the Add menu there's an option for 'New Group' (within the Group sub-menu). This will create your node group.

[image: inside node group]

You can rename the output sockets of the group using the properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>).

You can then add your group (Add/Group/NodeGroup) to your materials :

[image: node group]

Note that you can rename the node group by clicking in the Name field (it defaults to 'NodeGroup' but you can give it any name you like - such as 'Color Palette').

Making changes to the internal nodes of the group will affect anywhere that uses that group.

Comment: you can pin this group in a new viewport window to keep it handy

Comment: wow, I think I can use this trick to my another project, thank for the idea, but I need to insert keyframe to each changes of my color :)

Comment: You can keyframe the color of each of the RGB nodes if you need them to change.